# Lift on Airplane wing

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, aircraft, lift

Why commercial airplanes use long, slender wings? Isn't it to maximize lift, we make the plane's wings as wide as possible?

Comment: Much more suited to [aviation.se]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They need a particular amount of *wing area*, in order to get the desired amount of *wing loading* (weight per unit of area) at the speed they want to fly.
Then, drag is minimized if the *aspect ratio* (ratio of wing length to wing width) is maximized. So at a given area, they want long narrow wings.